# How to play wav file in Node.Js?

Tags: node.js, audio, wav

I need something simple: play an audio file from my node.js file. I've tried all sorts of things and cannot find anything that works. I'm currently trying "play-sound", from this link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/play-sound

I made sure to install play-sound, and then I have just the following as my code:

```
var player = require('play-sound')(opts = {})
player.play('chime.wav', function(err){
if (err) throw err
});
```

I get nothing. I can play the sound just fine from the command line with:

```
aplay chime.wav
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

**Update:** I figured it out. "node-aplay" worked for me: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-aplay

I didn't need the USB audio configuration part. I just installed node-aplay and alsa according to the instructions. My code was just the first two lines in the example:

```
var Sound = require('node-aplay');

// fire and forget: 
new Sound('/path/to/the/file/filename.wav').play();
```

Comment: node-wav-player is pretty good used it on Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** I figured it out. "node-aplay" worked for me: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-aplay

I didn't need the USB audio configuration part. I just installed node-aplay and alsa according to the instructions. My code was just the first two lines in the example:

```
var Sound = require('node-aplay');

// fire and forget: 
new Sound('/path/to/the/file/filename.wav').play();
```

Comment: This finally works to stop audio after starting it. Found anything less laggy? Doesn't seem to be much for buffering and start/stopping audio in node

Answer (score 1):

Try `sound-play` instead, it supports both `.wav` and `.mp3`:

```
const sound = require('sound-play')
sound.play('/path/music.wav')
```

Comment: WARNING: Doesn't work with Linux-based Operating Systems!!

Comment: It's written in the documentation only Mac and Windows are supported. Most audio-related applications are developed for them. However, if the Linux demands are higher in the future I'll look for a solution to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could see what was happening by checking `stdout` or `stderr`:

```
var player = require('play-sound')(opts = {})
player.play('chime.wav', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
   if (err) throw err
   console.log(stdout)                                                                                               
   console.log(stderr)
});
```